# PHP site freeze/crash but static contents fine

Tags: php, mysql, apache, vps

I have a PHP site where users upload a lot of photos. The photos are cropped in the front end and sent as base64 in a POST form. The max size is around 80kB.

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('image').src = dataurl;   To display croped image on the browser
document.getElementById('inddeninput').value = dataurl; To set hidden input value
```

**Then ajax call to submit to PHP**

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: `url/to/php/file`,
  data: formData,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  })
```

**The PHP script:**

```
$img = $_POST['img'];

$dataImg = base64_decode($img);

file_put_contents($fileLocation, $dataImg);
```

Then insert/update the MySQL(Mariadb) table with the location of the image.

```
$response = location of the image;
echo json_encode($response);
```

**Hosting:**

It's hosted on a VPS with 4CPU and 8GB. PHP 7.4 and Apache 2.4 running mpm_event.

**The Issue**

Everything's fine when there are fewer users.

When there are a lot of concurrent users (approximately 400), the entire site is very slow and takes 30 seconds or more to respond. However, there are no Apache error logs, no site error logs, nothing, and if I restart Apache its fine for a few minutes.

If I try to load a static file like an image from the site(mydomain.com/public/images/img.1.jpg) it is very fast and takes less than a second.

What things can I try to solve this?

### Edit

After a lot of digging around I found the issue in the /var/log/php7.4-fpm.log

```
[pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (96), consider 
raising it
```

It was the php_fpm module child connections. I had the following settings before:

```
pm.max_children = 96
pm.start_servers = 48
pm.min_spare_servers = 32
pm.max_spare_servers = 64
```

A lot of my users are on slow connections, and I guess subsequent requests went on queue. I have increased the values and the situation has improved.

Comment: _"Then insert/update the MySQL(Mariadb) table with the location of the image."_ What SQL statement are you using? What is your DB schema? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: That sounds like a memory problem. Any way you can run "top" and see how much the process consumes?

Comment: @kmoser  table_img_url: schema: id[int 11, Primary Auto, increament], user_id[varchar(24), indexed], img_url[varchar[128]]. Update table_img_url SET img_url = url WHERE user_id = 'user_id';

Comment: @Deiter The "top" command shows 6Gb free and CPU is around 10us. Can you please tell me "how to view how much the process consumes"?

Comment: @Tumin Eliezer How much memory does it say apache2 process is consuming? This is while it is slow.

Comment: base64 increases the size of data. You should consider using the binary upload with standard `multipart/form-data` headers.

Comment: @Dieter This is what I got: USER: www-data VIRT: 2278.0m  RES: 21.1m   SHR: 7.0m COMMAND: apache2 there are around 10 of these lines.

Comment: @TumtinEliezer Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63915217/edit) to add relevant info, don't post it as a comment.